# php each visit redirects to next page in a sequence

Tags: php, redirect, sequential

I have a page that redirects to a random URL from a array of URLs.

```
<?php 
$urls = array("url01", 
          "url02", 
          "url03"); 
$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)]; 
header("Location: http://$url"); 
?>
```

This is cool, but what I would REALLY like is each time the page is visited, instead of randomly choosing a URL to redirect to, I would like it to redirect sequentially on each visit?

1. First visit redirects to url01
2. Next visit redirects to url02
3. Then next visit redirects to url03
4. Then next visit redirects to url01.co.uk again and so on...

Is this even possible?

Comment: Save the index in a session variable. Each time, increment the variable and redirect to that element of the array.

Comment: If you want to use it globally for different users, you should use DB or file to save current index. Else you could use session variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

session_start();
$curr = array_key_exists('curr', $_SESSION) ? $_SESSION['curr'] : 0;

$urls = array("url01", "url02", "url03");
$curr = $curr >= sizeof($urls) ? 0 : $curr;

$_SESSION['curr'] = $curr + 1;
header('Location: http://' . $urls[$curr]); 

?>
```

Comment: You should probably throw some comments in there.

Comment: That seems to be the badger, although upon testing, it kinda works in revers, takes me to url 3 then 2 then 1, then back to 3 again, but thats no biggie, does exactly what I need!
Cheers Deep!